# Applying the same test to all members of a collection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tdd, xctest

In a test I have a `NSArray` with several objects. They must all pass the same test.

Is there a better or more elegant way to express this than just doing a for-in and applying the same macro to each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a judgement call, but you could consider -indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:passingTest: and maybe -enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: as alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, and then your verification can be reused in other tests.

```c
- (void)testObjectsInArray {
    for (NSObject *obj in array) {
        [self verifyObject:obj];  
    }
}

- (void)verifyObject:(NSObject *)object {
    XCTAssert(object);
}
```